# Making a Global List variable to access from any activity

Tags: android, arraylist, global-variables

I am working on a shopping car app and need to have the product list and every product stock. for this what I am trying to do is implement a global list variable. I have read about global variables and I  could implement it, but can't figure out how a list would be. any suggestions or help on how to implement it would be great, thanks.

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private int data;

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int d){
        this.data=d;
    }
}

((Application) this.getApplication()).setData(0);
x1=((Application) this.getApplication()).getData();
```

Comment: Take a look at [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: if you want to develop shopping car application i think you need more knowledge than you know now.
According to your question u can read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724447/iterating-a-global-list-from-any-activity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will review your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out following your suggestions. first on the applicacion class

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {


    public ArrayList myGlobalArray = null;

    public Application() {
        myGlobalArray = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

then for the porpouse of my app I add the respective values on their respectives indexes

```
    for (int i=0;i<productsList.size();i++){
        if (productsList.get(i).idProduct==idProduct){
            values.add(i,Integer.parseInt(txtQuantity.getText().toString()));
            ((Application)getApplicationContext()).myGlobalArray = (ArrayList) values;
        }
    }
```

and when I need to get the values

```
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int d=0;d< ((Application) getApplicationContext()).myGlobalArray.size();d++) {
        test.add((Integer) ((Application)getApplicationContext()).myGlobalArray.get(d));
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using a `for each` in the place of `for` loops?